# Is this the correct way to rotate proxy in web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

i m trying to rotate proxy from a set of proxy_pool in web scraping. is this the correct way of doing by setting `page_response = ""` ?

```
page_reponse = ''
while page_reponse == '':
    proxy = next(proxy_pool)
    dict_proxy = {"http": proxy, "https": proxy}
    try:
        page_response = requests.get(iurl, headers=headers,timeout=tout, proxies=dict_proxy)
        break
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as rec:
        pass
```

how should i implement below statement in a code without using selenium :

```
try a proxy for 3 times and if still it gives error then only i should go to next proxy in the list
```